# var in style.setProperty does not render

Tags: javascript, html, css, document

I have a progress bar which increases based on numbers entered by the user:

```
<div class="progressBarContainer percentBar"> 
    <div class="progressBarPercent" style="--width:${gPercent}"  id="${gName}-pbar"></div> 
</div>
```

I use a variable in the style to define the width of the progress bar

```
.progressBarPercent {
  background-color: var(--progressbar-main-color);
  width: calc(var(--width, 0) * 1%); <== THIS
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1px);
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

This is how I try to update it:

```
document.getElementById(gName+"-pbar").style.setProperty('--width', calculatedPercent);
```

If I make a log, the new percentage is displayed correctly in the log, but the property of the element is not modified:

The element:
[The element image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jacX8.png)

The log:
[The log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5zik.png)

Comment: please avoid pasting screenshots, paste the code instead - especially for short bits like those

Comment: I tried and works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you posted seems to work fine, the problem must be something else.

Here is the example working:

```js
let progress = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  if (++progress > 100) progress = 0;
  document.getElementById("test").style.setProperty('--width', progress);
}, 100);
```

```css
:root {
  --progressbar-main-color: crimson;
}

.progressBarContainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.progressBarPercent {
  background-color: var(--progressbar-main-color);
  width: calc(var(--width, 0) * 1%);
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1px);
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBarContainer percentBar">
  <div class="progressBarPercent" style="--width:0" id="test"></div>
</div>
```